# React Native await AsyncStorage before export

Tags: firebase, react-native, async-await, export, asyncstorage

Depending on a user set preference from AsyncStorage I need to initialize one of two Firebase environments.  I have the snippet from the javascript file I'm using to set up the Firebase database, but as you can clearly see it will give me a syntax error on the await call.

What would be the best way to export the firebase symbol, but only after the appropriate initializeApp call has been made?

Thanks,

Red

---

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG, FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEMO, DATA_ENVIRONMENT_STORAGE_KEY } from '../../../shared/env';


async function initializeFirebase()
{
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(DATA_ENVIRONMENT_STORAGE_KEY);
    if ((value == null) || (value == 'live'))
        firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
    if (value == 'demo')
        firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEMO);
}
await initializeFirebase();

export var db = firebase.database();
export default firebase;
```

Comment: why are you exporting this? `export default firebase;`

Comment: @free-soul, thanks for commenting.  In full disclosure I'm new to React-Native and Firebase.  The source file is pre-existing and I am trying to modify it to point to any one of the two databases.  So to answer your question, I don't know why the original creator did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I understand is correct, you want is to initialize firebase, then create a db reference and export it.

Try this:

**initializeFirebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import {
    FIREBASE_CONFIG,
    FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEMO,
    DATA_ENVIRONMENT_STORAGE_KEY
} from '../../../shared/env';

async function initializeFirebase() {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(DATA_ENVIRONMENT_STORAGE_KEY);

    let firebaseConfig = null;
    if ((value === null) || (value === 'live')) {
        firebaseConfig = FIREBASE_CONFIG;
    } else if (value === 'demo') {
        firebaseConfig = FIREBASE_CONFIG_DEMO;
    }

    if (firebaseConfig !== null) {
        await firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        return firebase.database();
    }
}

export default initializeFirebase;
```

---

**someOtherFile.js**

```
import initializeFirebase from './initializeFirebase.js';

async someOtherFunction() {
    // ...    

    const database = await initializeFirebase();

    // ... do something with 'database'
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look into this.  It seems to me the source shown above exports initializeFirebase.  In fact, the code base expects firebase or db to be exported.  Doesn't exporting the initializeFirebase function mean all uses of firebase or db need to be refactored?

Comment: yes, we will need to modify all the places they are being used. But since `initializeFirebase` is an async action, doing this modification ensures database is initialized before using it.

Comment: So playing around a bit, I understand what I need to do in the code base in the spirit of your suggestion.  Marking your solution as works!